# Linq to SQL a good way to lock table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a method that checks if a certain record (with some id) in the database exists. If it does, it gets updated and if it does not, it gets created. This method is called from ASP.NET Web API so there can be many concurrent calls.

Now I use a classic .NET lock at the start of the method. It works but the performance is really poor (as expected, locking the whole method). Most of the request are not in conflict, working with different records.

Is there a better way to do it better utilizing Linq to SQL that I use?

Comment: Why even lock at all? SQL Server handles concurrent access pretty well .... and several readers reading n rows, while others are inserting new rows shouldn't really be any concern .....

Comment: Entity Framework has `.AddOrUpdate` for upserts.

Comment: @marc_s I lock because I do not want the record to be created twice. Image 1. requeste comes, no record exists, creates the recod, 2. request comes, no record exists (request 1 has not finished), creates the record .. now I have 2 records instead of one

Comment: @Aron the project uses Linq to SQL and I cannot switch

Answer (score 0):

How about you log the request in MSMQ, and have a handler that adds/updates the database. No locks required, and no slow down of Web API.

Comment: Not really a good solution for my case. The call to Web API is made from a web app using JavaScript and the web app needs to know then the request finished ok.